# Need to run designated lines for electric washer and dryer

Tags: electrical, dryer, washing-machine

I live in Pennsylvania. I need to run one line for an electric dryer and another line for an electric washer. Can you please tell me what wire type (or size) to use and what amp size to use in the breaker box, which is a GE that has spare spaces in it? The run is planned to be a surface run in conduit over to the appliances, in a basement.[image]

Comment: Is this run going to be exposed on the surface of a wall, or hidden away inside a wall? What make and model is your breaker box, for that matter?

Comment: Does the breaker box have spare spaces in it?

Comment: Also, is this run simply going over from the breaker box to a location in the same room, or does it have to go off into an adjacent room and/or around corners?  And I take it the breaker box is mounted sticking out from the wall it's on, right?

Comment: yes there are spare spaces and its just a short simple run from the box to the appliances which are all in the basement

Comment: Does your dryer already have a 4-prong plug on it, or are you going dryer-shopping as part of this?

Comment: I am going washer and dryer shopping. was hoping i could find appliances with the 3 prong plug

Comment: Can you post a photo of your breaker box? (Use the "edit" button in "share edit ..." below the left side of your post, then hit the button that looks like a stylized painting of a mountain and a moon to add a picture to it)

Comment: Also, if you were walking from the breaker box to the washer/dryer location, do you run into the washer's spot (where the water taps and drain pipe are) or the dryer's spot (where the vent pipe is) first?

Comment: the breaker box is the gray one at the bottom left. I will be drilling into the basement to run the line from that box.

Comment: Can you open the outer cover on the breaker box and post a photo showing the breakers inside?

Comment: sure I will do that tomorrow and post it thank you so much. sorry at work now

Comment: Why **was hoping i could find appliances with the 3 prong plug**? When installing a new line (a) code requires the 4-wire connection and (b) the cost difference is minimal.

Comment: ok thanks I have never worked with 4 prong, just thought it would be easier to wire the receptacle with 3 prong

Comment: The difference is the ground wire. Big deal to retrofit an existing installation. But really easy with a new installation. Also pretty much any dryer from the last 25 years can be switched easily from 3 to 4 or from 4 to 3.

Comment: Do you want to use the **conduit wiring method** every inch from the breaker panel to the washer and dryer receptacles?  Or do you want to flip back and forth between open cable and **conduit as anti-damage shield**?  The fiasco on the right appears to be an attempt at the latter.